# How do I change the order of WiFi Networks in Windows 8.1 to give priority to one over another?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

In Mac OS X you can change the order of remembered wireless networks by moving them up and down the list. This will change which WiFi network gets connected first.

I can't seem to find the equivalent setting in Windows 8.1. How can I change the settings so that I give preference to a particular network over another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 lacks a GUI way to do this which is unfortunate.

1. At an elevated (admin) command prompt run the following command to see the available wireless networks and their current priorities:

   ```
   netsh wlan show profiles
   ```

   [image: 1]
2. Note the name of the interface and the wireless network and use the following command to change the latter's priority:

   ```
   netsh wlan set profileorder name="w1r3l3$$" interface="Wi-Fi" priority=1
   ```
3. Running `netsh wlan show profiles` again will show you the changed order.

<sub>[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/131640/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wireless-networks-in-windows-8/)</sub>

Naturally people have made GUIs to overcome this ridiculous omission, so you can use something like [**WiFi Profile Manager 8**](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wifi-profile-manager-windows-8) instead:

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks for you help. I used the command line to move my network to the top spot "priority 1". I also experimented by trying to set another network also to "priority 1" as well to see if this worked or created a conflict. This pushed all the others in the list down a level. So I'm guessing the networks are numbered by priority and when you set a new priority for one of them, it simply slots one in and reorders them all accordingly

Comment: I also attempted to set priority to a higher number than the total number of networks and Windows returned `Priority order for profile <profile name> is **not** changed for "WiFi"`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script to allow users to edit this using notepad:

```
# Prioritize WLAN networks

# Prepare the temporary file
$tempfile = "$($Env:Temp)\wifiprio.txt"
Set-Content -Path $tempfile -encoding UTF8 @"
# Edit (re-arrange) the list of networks, putting the highest priority at the top.
# Empty lines and lines starting with # will be ignored.
#
"@

# Add the network list to the file
& netsh wlan show profiles | Where-Object {$_ -match(":")} | ForEach-Object {(($_.split(":"))[1]).trim()} | Out-File $tempfile -encoding UTF8 -Append

# Allow the user to edit the list
Start-Process -FilePath "notepad.exe" -ArgumentList $tempfile -PassThru -Wait

# Get the edited list
$networks = Get-Content $tempfile | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "^\s*#"} | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "^\s*$"}

# Clean up
Remove-Item $tempfile 

# Set priority according to the edited list
$priority = 1
ForEach ($network in $networks)
{
    & netsh wlan set profileorder name="$($network)" interface="Wi-Fi" priority=$priority
    $priority += 1
}
```