# What order are wifi-networks displayed in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, sorting

When you open the wifi menu on Windows, the order of the networks seems random. What order are they meant to be in?

Comment: Random (as found).

Comment: at least you can specify the priority: https://superuser.com/a/994983/1125377

Comment: Mine are always displayed in the order of signal strength, strongest to weakest. The order between ones that have the same displayed strength may be determined by their exact strength which is not displayed.

Comment: Alternative: Use a third-party  tool such as Nirsoft's WifiInfoView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html , click on a column header (e.g., *Signal Quality*), and the list is sorted on that column.